# Rows not rendering in React Native ListView from MobX store

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I'm trying to render a ListView with section headers in React Native (0.33) and the section headers are rendering but not the rows. The data is coming from a mobx store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out ListView tries to figure out it's own rowIndices by calling Object.keys(...) and expecting an array of integers (which are the array indices) but it doesn't work on ObservableArrays.

My solution here is that when you cloneWithRowsAndSections, you can use .slice() to change to a normal array an then easily get the section ids like this:

```
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(
    list,
    Object.keys(list),
    Object.keys(list).map((sectionID) => Object.keys(list[sectionID].slice()))),
```

Comment: What is the structure of the data in the store?